# SFINAE and visibility-checking in Clang vs. GCC vs. MSVC -- which is correct?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, c++03, access-specifier

I've written my attempt at a C++03-compatible implementation of `is_default_constructible`:

```
template<class = void> struct is_default_constructible;
template<> struct is_default_constructible<>
{
protected:
    // Put base typedefs here to avoid pollution
    struct twoc { char a, b; };
    template<bool> struct test { typedef char type; };
    template<class T> static T declval();
};
template<> struct is_default_constructible<>::test<true> { typedef twoc type; };
template<class T> struct is_default_constructible : is_default_constructible<>
{
private:
    template<class U> static typename test<!!sizeof(::new U())>::type sfinae(U*);
    template<class U> static char sfinae(...);
public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(sfinae<T>(0)) > 1;
};
```

When I test it in GCC (`-std=c++03`), it returns `0` because the constructor is invisible:

```
class Test { Test(); };

int main()
{
    return is_default_constructible<Test>::value;
}
```

When I test it in Visual C++ (different versions all have the same behavior), I get back `1`.

And when I test it in Clang (also `-std=c++03`), I get:

```
error: calling a private constructor of class 'Test'
template<class U> static typename test<!!sizeof(::new U())>::type sfinae(U *);
                                                      ^
note: while substituting explicitly-specified template arguments into function template 'sfinae' 
static bool const value = sizeof(sfinae<T>(0)) > 1;
                                 ^
note: in instantiation of template class 'is_default_constructible<Test>' requested here
return is_default_constructible<Test>::value;
       ^
error: calling a private constructor of class 'Test'
template<class U> static typename test<!!sizeof(::new U())>::type sfinae(U *);
                                                      ^
note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'sfinae' [with U = Test]
static bool const value = sizeof(sfinae<T>(0)) > 1;
                                 ^
note: in instantiation of template class 'is_default_constructible<Test>' requested here
return is_default_constructible<Test>::value;
```

Which compiler is correct and why?

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't be surprised if this was a duplicate, so please close if it is. It's not easy to search for though.

Comment: Please always specify the version when you say: with gcc, with clang, etc.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I didn't see why it might matter, but it's Clang 3.6.0 and GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It matters quite a bit considering that whether the visibility is considered in the SFINAE context or not has changed in in C++11. Compilers that predate that (or follow the old rules, including g++4.4) will fail due to the accesibility issue, while compilers that use the C++11 rules won't consider it.

Comment: @David: But I thought I already said I'm doing this in C++03 mode... shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @Mehrdad: we can discuss this as much as you want, but I can provide two different versions of gcc that will accept/reject the code. Does the version matter? Obviously, does it not? Ok, maybe not for the overaching question of which compiler is right in C++03... the code is invalid in C++03

Comment: Hmm. According to [N2634](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html), as late as 2008, access checking was *not* performed during substitution. I wonder when that changed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not valid C++03, although it is valid C++11. The g++ 4.8 compiler is abiding to the C++11 rules and ignoring inaccessible members in an SFINAE context, while clang compilers is abiding to the C++03 where the member (constructor in this case) is found and selected, but access checks make the code invalid. VS (whatever version you are using) is not abiding to C++11 or C++03 rules, it seems to be ignoring the access specifier inside the `sizeof` completely.

Comment: Either you mixed up the compilers or I'm not understanding your answer, because clearly VC++ doesn't think the code is invalid...

Comment: @Mehrdad: In VS you cannot control whether it builds in C++03 or C++11 mode, it has only one mode.  In C++03 the code is invalid (hard error), in C++11 access checking is done as part of the substitution process, SFINAE should kick in and pick the ellipsis overload. Summarizing: clang++ is correctly following the C++03 rules, g++ is following the C++11 rules (even with `-std=c++03`!), VS is not following C++03 nor C++11 rules correctly.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, what confused me was that you said the "other compilers" are abiding by C++03 which didn't make any sense but I see you fixed it now.